# Vertex normals not being calculated correctly

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, normals

I'm trying to calculate normals by multiplying 3 vectors to extrude vertices along those normals, it only works for half of the object, see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMYsj.png) image as a reference (the pink lines represent the extruded vertices)

here's how the normals are calculated:

```
    for (Vertex& v : vertices)
    {

        glm::vec3 normal = { 0,0,0 };

        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
        {
            const glm::vec3& a = vertices[i].position;
            const glm::vec3& b = vertices[i + 1].position;
            const glm::vec3& c = vertices[i + 2].position;

            glm::vec3 n = (b - a) * (c - a);
            
            normal += glm::normalize(n);
        }

        v.normal = glm::normalize(normal);
    }
```

EDIT1:
I tried to use glm::cross(b-a, c-a), but the output is always zero and the object now looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4thin.png)

this is the code:

```
    for (Vertex& v : vertices)
    {

        glm::vec3 normal = { 0,0,0 };

        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
        {

            const glm::vec3& a = vertices[i].position;
            const glm::vec3& b = vertices[i + 1].position;
            const glm::vec3& c = vertices[i + 2].position;

            glm::vec3 n = glm::cross( (b - a), (c - a) );
             
            normal += glm::normalize(n);
        }

        v.normal = glm::normalize(normal);
    }
```

also, the Y component in each vector is always equal to 0

EDIT 2:
The base shape is 2D and it only uses x,z components and then it gets extruded along y axis, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ2fL.png) is how the vertex processing works

-- Update --

I managed to fix the issue by first calculating the vertex tangent and then calculate the normal using that tangent, but that causes a small issue, when I change the position of the object, the tangents/normals calculation will deform the object and I guess it's a problem related to normalization, I might create a separate post for that, I'll include a link to that post when I create it.

```
glm::vec3 GetUnitNormal(const glm::vec2& p1, const glm::vec2& p2, const float s)
    {
        const glm::vec2 p3 = p1 + ( (p2 - p1) * s );
        const float m = (p3.y - p1.y) / (p3.x - p1.x);
        const float c = p1.y - m * p1.x;
        const float y = (m * p1.x) + c;

        const glm::vec2 tangent = glm::normalize(glm::vec2(p1.x, y));
        glm::vec3 normal = glm::vec3(-tangent.y, 0, tangent.x);

        return glm::normalize(normal);
    }
```

edit 4:
[here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69623115/changing-object-position-deforms-its-tangent-normals) the link to the post

Comment: Is your shape 2d?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. the base vertices are 2d and they only use x,z components and after the extrusion, the new object gets extruded along y axis

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Should the normal extend along the y axis? Then it is always (0,1,0) regardless of the vertex.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. sorry for confusion, I'm trying to calculate normals per-vertex so I can extrude those vertices along their normals which will give the shape a thickness, In the third image this is represented as the second step, I already know how to extrude them along y axis, that's the final step in the third image (which is located at the second edit)

Comment: You are calculating a normal vector. A normal vector is normal to some surface at some point on the surface. What surface is it?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. they are all triangular

Comment: Um sorry, I don't follow. You have a bunch of triangles. What surface do they approximate/lie in? If the surface is the xz plane, then the normal is (0,1,0) at every point and there is nothing to calculate. In any case the normal to a surface at a point is a **cross** product of two non-parallel vectors tangent to the surface at that point. A dot product as you seem to compute is a single number and has nothing to do with the normal vector. If your cross-product is zero, your vectors are parallel and you cannot compute the normal from them.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are using cross product and the * operator. That is defined as

```cpp
template<typename T, qualifier Q>
    GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER GLM_CONSTEXPR vec<3, T, Q> operator*(vec<3, T, Q> const& v1, vec<3, T, Q> const& v2)
    {
        return vec<3, T, Q>(
            v1.x * v2.x,
            v1.y * v2.y,
            v1.z * v2.z);
    }
```

It should be:

```cpp
glm::vec3 n = cross((b - a), (c - a));
```

Comment: using glm::cross( b-a, c-a ) I always get 0 as output, I edited the original post

Comment: @UserNotFound So what is `a`, `b` and `c`? The cross product is (0, 0, 0) if one of the vectors are (0, 0, 0) or the vectors pint in the same direction.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I can confirm that none of the vectors are 0/pointing to the same direction, I'm guessing that the origin of the problem is the shape itself since it's vectors are treated as 2d vectors (the Y component is always 0)

Comment: @UserNotFound If your vertices just have a x and y component, the result of the cross product has just a z component (0, 0, +/-z). This is the nature of a **normal** vector.

Comment: @UserNotFound you mentioned it only worked for half of the shape, i understand that you also need the normal in the other direction pointing towards the screen(just like in this picture) https://ibb.co/r5hrXxQ . If that is right all you need to do is to switch the arguments of the cross product to get the other vector. Because a x b != b x a